# Testing to see if item exists in a binded dropdown list based on a value

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I've been scouring the net, and can't seem to find a solution that works.

I have a page done in ASP.NET (in VB) that has a drop down list populated by an SQL query.

My dropdown list gets renders as follows (information slightly altered):

```
<select name="ddOptions" id="ddOptions">
<option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
<option value="test">test</option>
<option value="15">First Option</option>
<option value="16">Second Option</option>
```

I need to find out if there is an option the a value of "15" in this list.  I've tried many solutions out there, but none seem to work - I assume because I'm dealing with a binded dropdown list...?

Any help would be great.

Comment: You want to find it in VB.Net at server side?

Answer (score 4):

Add `runat="server"` to the Select control, so that you can access it on server side.

```
<select name="ddOptions" id="ddOptions" runat="server">
```

Then do like.. Please note this code is written in c#, you can convert it into vb.net

```
 ListItem li = ddOptions.Items.FindByValue("15");
    if (li != null)
    {
        // value found
    }
    else
    {
        //Value not found
    }
```

Comment: Used a version of this previously without luck... tried it again, no luck.

Comment: Here's what I did:  
`Dim li As New ListItem  
li = ddContraception.Items.FindByValue("15")   
If IsNothing(li) Then  
Label1.Text = "Not Found"  
Else  
Label1.Text = "Found"  
End If`

Comment: did you test it? did you get an issue?

Comment: Tested it - result is always null.

Comment: but your select control id is ddOptions is in your question, but here you have posted different one

Comment: I changed the ID I used in the OP, to give it a generic name. Forgot to change the ID name in the reply.

Comment: If I add an item to the list through code (ddOptions.Items.Add("15")), it will pick up the value with 15... which leads me to believe that it's an issue with the binding...